# Java Regex, strange error

Tags: java, regex

I will get a `false` if running the following code, but if I remove `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` from `Pattern.compile`, the result is true

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(?<!S)\\.a\\s*\\(\\s*\\)\\s*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String s = "attributes.a()";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This question needs a better title and description to be useful to people with the same problem who are looking for the answer. I can't think of a good title though... Could anyone help out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why is it strange? It is working as intended, perhaps due to the flag you passed as 2<sup>nd</sup> argument.

Let's take a look at your pattern: -

```
".*(?<!S)\\.a\\s*\\(\\s*\\)\\s*$"
```

Your pattern will match the string which does not have an `S` before `.a`. This is clear from the below part of your pattern.

```
(?<!S)\\.a  // Match if `.a` is not preceded by `S`.
```

Now, when you use `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, this condition will check for both `s` and `S`, before `.a` and if any of them is present, it will not match it. So your pattern literally becomes: -

```
(?<![sS])\\.a  // Match if `.a` is not preceded by `S` or `s`.
```

Now, in your string: -

```
"attributes.a()"
```

You have a small `s` before `.a`. So, the pattern in your code will return `true` for this string, with *case insensitivity* flag enabled.

---

Just FYI, you can also use `(?i)` flag instead of passing a second parameter for [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) to see the same effect. So the below pattern is same as yours: -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i).*(?<!S)\\.a\\s*\\(\\s*\\)\\s*$");
```

---

The advantage of using `(?i)` is that, you can use it to make only a part of your pattern `CASE_INSENSITIVE`. For e.g., if you want that you only check for `(?<!S)`, but the following string can be `.a` or `.A`, then you can use `(?i)` just before `.a`: -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(?<!S)(?i)\\.a\\s*\\(\\s*\\)\\s*$");
                                      ^^^
```

Now, the entire pattern after the `(?i)` flag will be matched in `CASE_INSENSITIVE` manner.

---

Also, note that, you don't really need a *look-behind* or *case-insensitive* matching here as pointed out in a comment. You can do it simply by using `[^S]` and `[aA]` if your letter is only supposed to be `a`. Because *look-behinds* and *case-insensitivity* brings with them some performance difference. So, you can simply change your pattern to: -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[^S][.][aA][ ]*[(][ ]*[)][ ]*$");
```

I also replaced *backslashes* with `character class`. I prefer using it, instead of double-escaping the meta-characters. But it's just a matter of taste. You can use whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually want to use it to match all `xxx.a()`, but not `S.a()`, any idea how to implement it? meaning I want to match to `attributes.a()` be `true`, but `S.a()` should be false

Comment: Then just don't use `case_insensitive`. Rest is all fine.

Comment: I want it to make `Attributes().A()` to true also

Comment: @green.. Here comes the need of `(?i)`. The beauty of this flag is that, you can add it at the position, from where you want to apply case_insensitivity. So, you can add it just before `.a`

Comment: Because the example regular expression is so short, one could apply `[^S]` instead of the look behind, `(?<!S)`, and then change the `a` to `[aA]`. This would allow one to avoid using case insensitive.

Comment: @pickypg.. Ah! true. Should have pointed that out. But good that you did that. Look-behind is really not needed here.

Comment: @Downvoter.. Care to explain your downvote, if you add one. OR post a better solution. And if you can't, then don't downvote.